# Есть json с товарами, как я могу вывести и создать категории

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, json

```
var test = '{ 
  "response": [ 
    {"name":"test1","category": 1}, 
    {"name":"test2","category": 2}, 
    {"name":"test3","category": 1}, 
    {"name":"test4","category": 1}, 
    {"name":"test55","category": 2}, 
  {"name":"test6","category": 5}, 
  {"name":"test5","category": 5}, 
  ]
}';
```

Есть массив, как его обработать jq и вывести на страницу в таком формате

```
<div>
<name>Категория: 1</name>
<p>test1</p>
<p>test3</p>
<p>test5</p>

<name>Категория: 2</name>
<p>test2</p>
<p>test55</p>

<name>Категория: 5</name>
<p>test6</p>
<p>test5</p>

<div>
```

Comment: У вас не валидный JSON.

Comment: это пример структуры

Comment: Ага. Не валидный пример структуры.

Comment: и вы думаете мы тут должны руками скопировать и править вашу структуру? хотите чтобы ответили - потрудитесь исходные данные в нормальном качестве предоставить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var data = { 
  "response": [ 
    {"name":"test1","category": 1}, 
    {"name":"test2","category": 2}, 
    {"name":"test3","category": 1}, 
    {"name":"test4","category": 1}, 
    {"name":"test55","category": 2}, 
    {"name":"test6","category": 5}, 
    {"name":"test5","category": 5}, 
  ]
};
//Создаем новый объект, в котором данные сгрупированы по категориям
var newData=[];
for(var i=0;i<data["response"].length;i++){
  if(newData[data["response"][i].category]==undefined){
   newData[data["response"][i].category]=[];
  }
  newData[data["response"][i].category].push(data["response"][i].name);
}
//Выводим данные
for(cat in newData){
  $("div").append("<name>Категория "+cat+"</name>");
  for(name in newData[cat]){
   $("div").append("<p>"+newData[cat][name]+"</p>");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script>
    var test = { 
        response: [ 
            {"name":"test1","category": 1}, 
            {"name":"test2","category": 2}, 
            {"name":"test3","category": 1}, 
            {"name":"test4","category": 1}, 
            {"name":"test5","category": 2}, 
            {"name":"test6","category": 5}, 
        ]
    };





    window.onload = () => {
        const category = Array.from(new Set(test.response.map((a) => a.category)));

        const ul = document.getElementById('ul');

        for (const cat of category) {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            li.textContent =  'Category ' + cat;
            const names = test.response.filter(v => v.category == cat).map(v => v.name);

            let innnerUl = ''

            for (const name of names) {
                innnerUl += `<li> Name: ${name}</li>`
            }

            innnerUl = `
            <ul>
                ${innnerUl}
            </ul>`;

            li.innerHTML += innnerUl;

            ul.append(li);

        }
    }


</script>
<body>
    <ul id="ul">

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А если в массиве будет еще if товара и цена, тогда как я могу вывести?